# How old is the Pogona genus?

Tags: evolution, zoology, phylogenetics, herpetology

What it says on the title, how old is the genus *Pogona*, which includes all bearded dragons? I tried looking online, and all I got was the useless answer of “bearded dragons are descended from their parents, who are descended from their parents… etc.”

Comment: Welcome to the site. What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not simply to be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to ask this question:

> How old is the most recent common ancestor of *Pogona* lizards and their closest relatives?

*Diporiphora* is a [sister clade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sister_group) of *Pogona*, as stated in Hugall *et al.* 2008.<sup>**1**</sup> Figure 4 of the same paper suggests that *Diporiphora* and *Pogona* diverged around 12 million years ago (see star in red box -- annotations mine):

> [image: Chronogram from Hugall 2008]
>
> <sup>An ultrametric chronogram generated from the Bayesian combined data phylogeny (Fig. 2C), under penalized likelihood rate smoothing (PLRS; optimal smoothing factor 80). The Riversleigh Physignathus calibration discussed in the text is used (indicated on figure as equal to 21 Mya). Tree pruned to show Australasian group only. Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) sampling 95% confidence interval shown for selected nodes.</sup>

So, a reasonable estimate for the age of the *Pogona* genus is **12 million years**.

---

**References**

1. Hugall AF, Foster R, Hutchinson M, Lee MSY. Phylogeny of Australasian agamid lizards based on nuclear and mitochondrial genes: implications for morphological evolution and biogeography, *Biological Journal of the Linnean Society*, Volume 93, Issue 2, February 2008, Pages 343–358.